# How do I get to the bottom of the Tower of the Moon?

Tags: torchlight-2

I've wiped out the Tower of the Moon. I've freed up Duros the Blade. My minimap shows no unexplored holes.

And yet, treasure awaits me.

[image]

What did I miss? Will there maybe be more quests later here that will open this gate as well?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are some golden gongs around the dungeon which are clickable, but don't show up when you press alt. Hit them all with a weapon.

Then the door will open.

[image]

Comment: I've found and rang three - and yet nothing. I don't see any more. EDIT: Whoops, the fourth is by the NPC you're supposed to rescue in the first place, by the closed gate.

Comment: Robotic arm past this gate also.